# create a number of form items based on user input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a value inputted by the user. How do I create a certain number of form items for the user to fill out, in either javascript/jQuery or PHP?

Eg.

```
<select id = "Fooinput" name = "Foo">
    <option value = "0">0</option>
    <option value = "1">1</option>
    <option value = "2">2</option>
    <option value = "3">3</option>
    <option value = "4">4</option>
</select>
<button id ="fooclick">Button</button>
<div id="fillout"></div>
```

and something like this in jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var inputnum = $("Fooinput").val();
  $("#foobutton").click(function(){
      for (var i=0; i<inputnum;i++){
          $("#fillout").append('<select id="uniqueid">OPTIONS</select>');
      } 
  });
});
```

I'm happy to see a solution in either jQuery or PHP, I just don't understand how I can later retrieve the values by giving all the select boxes a unique ID.

Comment: Are you actually giving them *unique* IDs, or are you giving them all *the same* "unique" ID?  If the latter then you're creating invalid markup, so any behavior at that point is undefined.  If the IDs truly are unique then you would reference the form elements just like any other form element: `$('#uniqueid')`  Can you elaborate a little more on specifically what the issue is and what isn't working?

Comment: @David, OP seems to be aware that the IDs need to be unique. The crux of the question is _how_ to make them unique when dynamically creating the elements.

Comment: I want them to all have unique IDs of course. I understand that isn't what this code does. I'm asking for similar code that would give these boxes unique ids

Comment: If that's the case then the answer below will work provided that the functionality is only ever invoked once on the page.  (Or if the results are "cleared" before it's invoked again.)  If it needs to be invoked multiple times then you may be able to store a "current max ID" variable and use that to keep increasing the `inputnum` value being used to create the `id`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give unique id `inputnum`   in loop

```
$("#fillout").append('<select id="uniqueid'+inputnum+'" class="Dropdown">OPTIONS</select>');
```

So id will be unique like `uniqueid0` , `uniqueid1` etc.

Then you can access it , using unique id , Use event like

```
$(".Dropdown").click(function(){
    $(this).attr(id);
});
```

Check using Inspect element, [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u51c9h3t/)  , You get unique id , here in this case i hardcoded `1` But same value will be looped in your code.

Comment: Okay great, thanks. This might be a silly question, but once I have done this, if I want to add all of the values from the created dropdown boxes to a session array, is there some kind of foreach loop I can use?

Comment: Shouldn't you close the double-quotes (on the `id` attribute) _after_ you append the counter value?

Answer (score 1):

This code will do the trick

**NOTE** : I moved the `var inputnum = $("Fooinput").val();` inside of the click event because as OP you will get value on page load not on click.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $("#foobutton").click(function(){
      var inputnum = $("Fooinput").val();
      for (var i=0; i<inputnum;i++){
          $("#fillout").append('<select id="uniqueid-'+$i+'">OPTIONS</select>');
      } 
  });
});
```